# I'm learning PHP and my include is not working

Tags: php

I'm at my first steps in PHP and i'm trying to import a file with some functions but it is not working.

I tryed to use include, include_once, require. function.php is in the same directory.

```
<?php
    include 'function.php';

    $accounts = [ ... ];

    $accounts['123.456.789-10'] = withdraw(
        $accounts['123.456.789-10'],
        500
    );
```

function withdraw is in function.php file.

> Warning: include(function.php): failed to open stream: No such file or
> directory in banco.php on line 2
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening 'function.php' for inclusion
> (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in banco.php on line 2
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sacar() in
> banco.php:19 Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 {main}   thrown in banco.php on line 19

Comment: check your function path. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: what is the location of your `function.php`? Is it at the same location as `banco.php`?

Comment: USe like `require_once __DIR__ . '/function.php';`

Comment: Yes Dhaval, is in the same location, IntelliJ phpStorm recognize it but still not working.

Comment: The default locations used for `include` or `require` are set by `php.ini` so check where this default is by using `echo get_include_path();` or set your own using `set_include_path(PATH)`

Comment: still not working with ``` include __DIR__ . '/function.php'; or require_once __DIR__ . '/functio```

Comment: Make sure the file can be accessed. Check who the owner/group is.

Comment: @RamRaider it's show me: .;C:\php\pear

Comment: Try this `print_r(dirname(__FILE__))` in `function.php` file to get whole path

Comment: It show me a dot. 
.

Comment: `;C:\php\pear` include this in an environment variable of your system.

Comment: How did you run your program? Are you running on a web server or just command line interface?

Comment: i'm running just > php bancos.php

Answer (score 0):

check the permissions of the file you are including and the state of letters capital or small every thing must be the same